# Can a python asycio coroutine have a code path with no await?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Are there any problems or side effects with a coroutine having a code path that does not contain an await statement?

Consider this example where a callback is provided to a coroutine as an argument, but that callback may be a regular function or a coroutine:

```
import asyncio
import inspect

async def foo(mycallback):
    if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(mycallback):
        await mycallback()
    else:
        mycallback()
...
```

Trying simple examples in the python console seem to suggest that there are no problems, but was wondering if there are more subtle issues that may arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't await, then you block the other bits of code that should be running, because asynch is about sharing ressources. So if the regular code is running fast, it's not much of a problem, but if it can be slow, it's blocks everything.

In regular code, an alternative to asynch is thread based programming. Here Python interrupts your code when it feels like it to run other threads, so there you have less of a blocking problem.

Comment: So basically the subtle side effect is related to the blocking time of the non-awaited code path.  If that blocking time is tolerable then no problem, otherwise reconsider the design.